# Question regarding deriving the AUC value

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, auc

I have a dataset (auc_data) which includes the response variable (y) and the predicted probabilities (y_hat). I have calculated the AUC value based on this data.

[image]

You can see that there are 3 rows in the data set which both y and y_hat are exactly zero. I just want to know that if I know the AUC based on "auc_data" dataset(which turns out to be 0.9167), is there any way to derive the AUC of "auc_data1" dataset (auc_data1=data set without those the 3 rows where both y and y_hat are exactly zero ) ,without actually calculating it?

Any suggestions are highly appreciate